# Count number of semicolon in single cote

Tags: shell

hi i want to count numer of semicolon in single cote

```
UPDATE T1 FROM abc T1,def T2 SET RECORD_END_TS = T2.a - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
,updatets = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) WHERE T1.name = 'first;last'AND T1.address = 'last;address';
```

There is two single cote statement in my query

```
WHERE T1.name = 'first;last'AND T1.address = 'last;address';
```

I want the output as 2 because there is two semicolon statement in single cote but i am getting as 3 with grep command

i  have tried with grep commend

```
total_semicolon=`DML| grep -o ';' | wc -l`
```

*DML is the full query

Comment: can one single quote pair wrap multiple semicolons?  like `'a;b;c;d'`

Comment: Yes, you have as output 3 because you have 3 semicolons one : (first;last) second : (last;address) and third (address';).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this one-liner a try:

```
awk -F"'" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)c+=(i%2==0?gsub(/;/,"",$i):0)}END{print c}'
```

It works for single/multiple `;` in same quote pair cases, some tests:

```
kent$  echo "foo ';b;;;' bar;;;;;;;;;;;"|awk -F"'" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)c+=(i%2==0?gsub(/;/,"",$i):0)}END{print c}'
4

kent$  echo "foo ';b;;;' 'foo;,bar;' ;;;;"|awk -F"'" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)c+=(i%2==0?gsub(/;/,"",$i):0)}END{print c}'   
6
```